# How to iterate over rings in a raster grid?

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, grid, geometry

We are at any given position in two dimensional the space. This space is divided in quadratic cells. I want to loop over all cells in a given distance, in order of their distance to us. That could happen in rings of increasing size for example. The order of cells with nearly equal distance doesn't matter.

How to loop over those cells in order of their distance to a given position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the simplification to integer grid coordinates is ok (as your remark on "nearly equal distance" suggests), you can do go through the cells ring-wise with increasing distance with the code below. If you have a starting point different from (0,0) you just need to add that to each generated point. The key ideas are:

1. starting from `(d,0)` we iteratively look for a neighbouring point with a "similar" distance (integer part = `d`) in counter-clockwise direction around `(0,0)` until we reach the starting point.
2. each point will have (except for the neighbour we came from) at most one direct neighbouhr (via edge) with "similar" distance. If there is no direct neighbour then there is exactly one diagonal neigbour with "similar" distance (again except for the previous neighbour).
3. the vector to the next neighbour is "almost" orthogonal to the vector to the origin.

Here is the code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> int sgn(T val) {
    return (T(0) < val) - (val < T(0));
}

int dist(double dx, double dy)
{
    return (int)sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}

typedef std::pair<int,int> TPoint;
typedef std::vector<TPoint> TPoints;

void generateNeighbourRing(int d, TPoints& ring)
{
    int dx = d;
    int dy = 0;
    do
    {
        ring.push_back(TPoint(dx,dy));
        int nx = -sgn(dy);
        int ny = sgn(dx);
        if (nx != 0 && dist(dx+nx, dy) == d)
            dx += nx;
        else if (ny != 0 && dist(dx, dy+ny) == d)
            dy += ny;
        else
        {
            dx += nx;
            dy += ny;
        }
    } while (dx != d || dy != 0);
}

int main()
{
    TPoints points;
    const int d_max = 4;
    for (int d = 0; d <= d_max; ++d)
        generateNeighbourRing(d, points);
    printf("spiral for dmax=%d (%d points):\n", d_max, points.size());
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<points.size(); ++i)
        printf(" (%d,%d),", points[i].first, points[i].second);
    printf("\n");
}
```

### **Plausibility of correctness:**

Let us look at images first where cells with equal distances to the center cell have the same color (once the distance is truncated, once the distance is rounded):

[image: distance truncated]  --  --  --  --  --  --  [image: distance rounded]

With `(dx,dy)` we iterate over the cells of a ring with equal distance; `(nx,ny)` is a kind of normal vector, which is constant along each half-axis and within each quadrant:

[image]

The black arrows show `(nx,ny)` for each region; the blue arrows show the directions into which a (direct) neighbour with equal distance is searched for first.

Next we need to consider which configurations of neighbours with equal distance are possible. Since the quadrants are rotationally symmetric it suffices to look at the first quadrant. The distance to the center cell between two direct neighbours can differ by at most 1; diagonally towards or away from the center the distance differs by 1 or 2:

[image] . . . [image]

(This follows from straight forward inequalities.) The important conclusion is that a 2x2 block of equal distances cannot happen; at most 4 neighbours can have the same distance forming a "zig-zag":

[image: no 2x2 block of equal distances]  . . . [image: max 4 neighbours]

Another important conclusion is that each cell has at least 2 neighbours with equal distance, again only in certain configurations. From this it can be reasoned that if the neighbours along the blue arrows have a different distance then the neighbour along the black arrow has the same distance. Thus all points put into the variable `ring` have distance `d`. (Note that in the second `else`-branch the distance is not checked.)

Next we go for the termination of the `do ... while`-loop. Note that with each iteration the angle between the line (0,0)-(dx,dy) and the positive x-axis increases. Since the distance stays the same we will finally leave the current quadrant and go into the next one. And since along the half-axis each distance appears exactly once we will finally arrive at the starting point (d,0).

From this it also follows that no point is taken twice: Within one call of `generateNeighbourRing` starting an iteration of the `do ... while` loop with the same point again would lead to an infinite loop and hence contradict the termination. Across several calls of `generateNeighbourRing` all points are different because of different distances to the center cell.

Looking at the possible configurations with neighbours with the same distance one can also show that all points with given distance `d` will be collected.

Comment: There is a hypot() or hypotf() function that could be used to simplify calculation of the distance. At the same time, you would fix the possible integer overflow in your dist() function.

Comment: Is your approach guaranteed to not find the same cell twice?

Comment: @Ulrich thanks for pointing out std::hypot. Concerning overflow: my previous version would overflow with integer arguments of size 2^16 (because the cast to float would happen after integer multiplication), but when using doubles from the beginning there will be no overflow with integer arguments and no loss accuracy (doubles have a 48-bit mantissa which easily holds a 32-bit integer)

Comment: @danijar There are several conditions needed: A) no cell is taken twice, B) no cell is omitted, C) the do-while loop terminates. Condition B is at least as tricky as A. Both follow from the key observation about the neighbour structure of cells with same rounded distance, which is the "key idea 2." above. This imposes an order on which neighbour to choose first (direct "edge" neighbours are preferred over diagonal neighbours). All three conditions are guaranteed by the above algorithm. I see that I should elaborate that in more detail. I hope I find the time.

Comment: @coproc That would be great because haven't understand you algorithm completely. However, you comment helped and I am able to implement that anyway.

Comment: Would this be extendable to 3D space or no chance?

Comment: whats T(0) doing  ?